# How to align in the middle of \underline{} with another formula?

Tags: equations, align, underline

I want to realize the following formula in latex.

[image]

I've tried

```latex
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[c]
    \underline{\mathrm{Primal}\,\,&\mathrm{problem}}
    % \mathrm{Primal}\,\,&\mathrm{problem}
    \\
    \underset{X}{\max}\quad&\mathrm{tr}\left( \mathsf{A}X \right) 
    \\
    \mathrm{s}.\mathrm{t}.\quad&\varphi \left( X \right) =\mathsf{B},
    \\
    &X\ge 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

However, there's an error using & notation inside \underline. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center `Primal problem`, `gather*` is a good choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \text{\underline{Primal problem}} \\
  \begin{aligned}
    \text{maximize:}   & \quad \langle A,X\rangle \\
    \text{subject to:} & \quad \Phi(X) = B, \\
                       & \quad X \in \text{Pos}(\mathcal{X})
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]